# Django query set based on user subscription plan

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-users

So I'm trying to build a web app,

the idea is I have data about homes all over the US,
and I don't want to show all data to users,
user will pay a monthly price (like a plan) based on number of states he selected when he subscribed,
So How can I make my models, user models and views so that he can only see data within the states he selected ?
and how can I represent these subscription plans as a model in my db ?

a small hint can make difference, so please give it if you don't have time to explain with example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities out there...
You can think about `User Groups` - so a User can be part of the group `Alaska` and `California`. (This options makes only sense because the states are not dynamically).

Another option (more likely) is to have a model for the states and a model for the selected states for a single User.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class States(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class UserStates(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  state = models.ForeignKey(States)
  available_since = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for quick the response @nrhode ,
 so one last thing I want to ask about,
  how can I manage subscriptions, for example to check if they are ended or not, so that the user can re pay again.

Comment: one more thing, I'm actually gonna do it by county not state,
and sometimes county names can be same for different states,
is there a best practice to solve this issue ?

Comment: @Ibrahim tbh if you need to ask it on this level, you are unlikely to be ready to undertake such a project directly. I would advise learning about data structures and /or sql a bit first at least.

Comment: @Gnudiff thanks for the advice,
I know I'm a beginner,
 but I still can learn from you guys,
and I know about foreign keys (one to many relationships), 
 but I'm trying to know the best practices so that I don't have to make changes in future when I want to scale.

Comment: I currently have a home model, and this model has state and county fields,
do you think I need to make a separate model that will have the state and county and make a one to many relation between it and current home model ?